# Uploading image to firebase storage (KOTLIN)

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-storage

To retrieve an image in the gallery, most tutorials show the usage of

```
startActivityForResult()
```

It is currently deprecated, I have found this [Basics of Intents](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result#launch) as a substitute. The code block does return a URI, however, when I use that uri to set an image or to upload to firebase storage, it does not work.

Flow of getting and uploading the image:

- Click the profile picture
- Pick from file storage or gallery
- After choosing, it would automatically set the image in the view and upload it to firebase storage associated with the auth ID of the current logged in user.

I have this in a fragment:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    getContent = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.GetContent()) { uri: Uri? ->
        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
            sharedViewModel.uploadImage(uri)
        }
        binding.ivProfilePic.setImageURI(uri)
    }
}
```

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

    binding.ivProfilePic.setOnClickListener{
        getContent.launch("image/*")
    }
}
```

while this is the code for uploading to firebase:

```
private val storageRef = Firebase.storage.reference

fun uploadImage(path: Uri?){
    val file = Uri.fromFile(File(path?.path!!))
    storageRef.child("images/${UUID.randomUUID()}").putFile(file)
}
```

I think I am missing something here.

I appreciate the help.

Comment: "it does not work" doesn't provide enough information so we can help. What exactly doesn't work? Do you have any errors?

Comment: Besides that, since you're using Kotlin, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-upload-an-image-to-cloud-storage-and-save-the-url-in-firestore-42711ca1df46) will definitely help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/CloudStorageJetpackCompose).

Comment: oh, I just realized that I put the code inside a try block without properly fetching in-case an exception happens. now, it outputs could not locate file for uploading:file:///document/image%3A1000000036, would it be related to how many slashes are there in the file path?

Comment: I think the problem has to do with the path, idk if it is when the Uri was fetched or passed along the functions.

Comment: thanks for the resource, I'll give it a thorough read

Comment: `val file = Uri.fromFile(File(path?.path!!))` If you do not show the full path value of path variable we have no idea what you do. The use of the File class is already strange as you will never get a file path if you let the user pick a file. Better start with exactly showing how you let the user do that. And then tell us which content scheme you got as you will not have got a file scheme/path.

Comment: sorry for the late reply,

`getContent = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.GetContent()) { uri: Uri? -> Log.i("TAG", uri.toString())`


returns `content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A1000000036`


I am currently focusing on the displaying of image in the view.

I am new to Uris, but I think I am doing something wrong or probably lack the steps on fetching.

I'm new to android so I'm not entirely sure what the path should look like. Are there any key parts I should always look at?

Comment: I'm also new to the File class, so I think I'm also doing something wrong there. I'm not sure what a file scheme or path is, I think it's somewhat like of a blueprint? But I have no idea what it properly should look like. I only took the implementation as mentioned here [link] (https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result#launch) and put it inside an onClickListener of an image. I'll do some reading on File class and paths in android.

Comment: I think I should also note that the image was made using the camera in the android emulator. Then the onClickListener fetches from a gallery or storage.

Comment: these are the results from each:

`registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.GetContent())`
->  content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A32

`path?.path!!` -> /document/image:32
`File(path?.path!!)` -> /document/image:32
`Uri.fromFile(File(path?.path!!))` -> file:///document/image%3A32

Comment: I just found this [youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lp9Qlij91Mo) and mine is similar in nature. however, his runs on the Activity while I run mine inside a fragment, does it have to do with the code not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution!

for the `registerActivity`, I've used the photo picker support library [link](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/photopicker#add-dependency)

I also added this dependency `implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.6.1'` as discussed in the documentation.

for the uploading to firebase I think I was just confused with the usage the File class and Uris. I could've passed the Uri at first, I was probably confused with the new keywords (File and Uri) and just jumped and the copy pasted the code.

this is the code I arrived at:

I've moved the `registerForActivityResult` code outside the onCreate() and just  a child of the Fragment class.

```
private val pickMedia = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.PickVisualMedia()) { uri ->
    if (uri != null) {
        binding.ivProfilePic.setImageURI(uri)
        sharedViewModel.uploadImage(uri)
    } else {
        // insert code for toast showing no media selected
    }
}
```

on onViewCreated():

```
binding.ivProfilePic.setOnClickListener{
pickMedia.launch(PickVisualMediaRequest(ActivityResultContracts.PickVisualMedia.ImageOnly))
}
```

and for uploading to firebase:

I've just passed the Uri

```
fun uploadImage(path: Uri){
        storageRef.child("images/${UUID.randomUUID()}").putFile(path)
            .addOnSuccessListener {
                // Display upload complete
            }
    }
```

thank you for the help